# Getting 401 when making a call to AWS Cognito secured endpoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito user pool.
The pool has an application integration for JavaScript that does not have a secret.
I am able to login using the following code

```
  private static async signin(role: UserRole): Promise<string> {
    const user = getUser();

    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: user.username,
      Pool: "myuserpool"
    });

    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: user.username,
      Password: user.password
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: result => {
          this.credentials[role] = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
          resolve(this.credentials[role]);
        },
        onFailure: err => {
          console.log(`Failed login to cognito with ${role}: `, err);
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

When I make a call to my endpoint with the aws-api-gateway-client, I can see the token attached, but it always returns a 401 unauthorized.

It's super confusing because I can take this token and paste it into the ApiGateway Authorizer and receive a 200 ok.  So it seems the token is valid, just not working properly.

EDIT:
Here is the flow....

- I have a Cognito user pool
- I can login to that userpool with a username / password and get a token back
- I then set "Authorization": "bearer {token}" on the aws-api-gateway-client request headers.
- The request fails with a 401 Unauthorized
- If I take that same token and paste it in the test section of the ApiGateway Authorizer, It tells me the token is valid.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused - Isn't this problem all about API Gateway not accepting your request due to permissions? What does Cognito have to do with it? Also please attach code that could be relevant understanding the problem - You have errors in an api we don't even know what it does / how it looks like - A bit hard to know what your issue is here

Comment: A likely problem here is that you're trying to use aws with the wrong profile. See `~/.aws/credentials` to see the profiles you configured, then make sure to run `export AWS_PROFILE=<profile-to-use>` to set the right profile

Comment: For your first comment, my Cognito userpool is set up as the API Gateway authorizer, I should have been more clear on that.  For the second  comment, I'm not using the aws cli, so my profiles shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the "bearer" part for the header value.  Cognito authorizers are just looking for the key/token.  Try a header of `"Authorization" : "<token_goes_here>".`

Comment: You are correct, Bearer is optional with AWS but it is allowed, because it is part of the formal specification.  Regardless, I tried and didn't work.